# Pi Camera: Raspberry Pi 3B+'s red led blinking

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, python, power, raspicam

I'm developing a project based on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ which utilizes an original Raspberry Pi Camera module. I'm powering the RPi from a 12V 4-cell LiPo, brought down to 5V by a power distribution board, to which I connnect the RPi via a usb cable. No devices other than the camera (which is connected via the CSI interface) are powered from the Pi itself - it only has 4 PWM channels connected, SDA & SCL, one gpio to read from and 4 Tx/Rx.

The problem is that when I run my program (which simply reads the video stream from imutils's PiVideoStream) and the camera module activates, the RPi's red led starts to blink, which, as far as I know, signalises voltage drops. Anyway, the camera works fine, I can obtain the data, but CPU temperature slowly begins to rise. As soon as I turn off the program, the camera turns off as well (judging by the camera's built-in led) and everything is back to normal.

Is there any way to fix this? And how is it even possible that an RPi with an official camera module causes voltage drops?

Comment: It is far more likely that your "power distribution board" (whatever that may be) is inadequate. "CPU temperature slowly begins to rise"is normal when the Pi is performing a resource intensive task.

Comment: The pdb itself is just a board which has 12V->5V converters on it. I know the rise in CPU temperature is normal during heavy CPU operations, but it reaches 70 degrees, while CPU usage is only at 30-35%. The thing that worries me the most is the red light suggesting a voltage drop

Comment: There is no such thing as " just a board which has 12V->5V converters"; what are the specifications? It **OBVIOUSLY** is not adequate.

Comment: Alright, sorry for my inadvertency, here are the [specifications](https://photos05.redcart.pl/templates/images/description/995/Image/kuba/27_czerwiec/pl/Pytka_zasilajca_PDB-XT60_W_2xBEC_12V_i_5V_-_MATEK.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed this by editing the boot config and disabling the Pi camera power led